# Waiting requests are canceled when pressing ESC anywhere in the browser

Tags: java, javascript, browser, cross-browser

I'm implementing an application using long pooling, with Java Servlet 3.0's `AsyncContext`.

As you know, there always should be an open connection listening to the server and receiving the push notifications. I have no problem with that but the following problem occurs:

When pressing `ESC` key wherever in the browser (either when nothing is selected or when I'm focused in a textfield / textarea) the request which should be kept opened is closed by the browser.

Is the expected behaviour?
Is there a cross-browser way to stop this behaviour?

*I tested this on Chrome and Mozilla using Firebug*

*I know that I could fire a new request attaching an `keyup` event on `body` but this may become error prone in a large JS document using lots of event.stopPropagation()*

LE: The Firebug log:

[image]

Comment: We use socket.io and I have never noticed anything like this. Are you sure there is no custom event listener listening to ESC somewhere?

Comment: @David I tested the feature with no listeners attached to key events and I got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

There is an outstanding bug on Mozilla regarding this issue, which was first eported back in 2010.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=614304

"Pressing ESC aborts open XMLHttpRequests in Firefox.  This doesn't happen in other browsers (except in WebKit, but only if the XHR was initiated before the page finished loading)."

As a workaround I would suggest you could capture any ESC presses. With jQuery you could to the following:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 27) { return false };
});
```